# Google CSE 403 error

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

When running our custom search engine, we are getting 403 Forbidden.
We do not have IP restrictions
Our account is set up with correct payment so it is not that we have gone over a limit

We use our CSE to search company names to try and find their website.

Many thanks,

Rob